# How to do multiple actions in case when then in sql?

Tags: sql, case-when

I want to do something like this:

```
select sum(case ttt.ind = 1 then 1 else 0 end) from ttt
```

I want to add a column to this query, called `myresult` which indicates if the value of `ttt.istry` is equal to 1.

Maybe like:

```
select 
    sum(case ttt.ind = 1 then 1, ttt.istry as myresult else 0 end) 
from ttt
```

of course I got an error...

How would I do that?

My data is:

```
ttt.ind | ttt.istry
--------+----------
   1    |     0
   0    |     1
   1    |     1
```

and so on...

Expected result:

```
ttt.ind | ttt.istry | myresult | sum
--------+-----------+----------+------
   1    |     0     |    0     |  2
   0    |     1     |   null   |  2
   1    |     1     |    1     |  2
```

Comment: Could you give us some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Where does the sum `2` comes from?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which database so I'll assume it's a modern one. You can use a window function and a `CASE` clause to do this.

For example:

```
select
  ind,
  istry,
  case when ind = 1 then istry end as myresult,
  sum(ind) over() as sum
from ttt
```

See live example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fa04a/1).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit hard to follow, but your result set suggests:

```
select ind, istry,
        (case when istry = 1 then 1
              when sum(istry) over (partition by ind) = 1 then 0
         end),
        sum(ttt.ind) over () as sum_ind
from ttt;
```